# Conditional Expectation Discrete and Continuous

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

[image]

Find $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$

So for the expectation so far I got that:

$$E[X] = E[X|N=n]P(N=n) = \large\frac{n+1}{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$
but for conditioning on both a discrete and continuous random variable I am not sure whether to use the summation or integration. For integration it comes out to be just $\frac{n+1}{\lambda}$ which does not seem right since that would indicate that the expectation is independent of each other.

Answer (score 4):

The mean of a Gamma or Erlang distribution $\Gamma(k,\lambda)$ is $k/\lambda.$

Then $$E(X)=E(E(X | N))=E\left(\frac{N+1}{\lambda}\right)=\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think your first step should be $$E[X] = \sum_{n\ge 0} E[X \mid N=n] P(N=n).$$

---

Adding some details:

We first find a nice result using the Taylor series of the exponential.

> \begin{align*}
> e^x &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{n!} x^n\\
> xe^x &=\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{n!} x^{n+1}\\
> e^x(x+1) &=\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{n+1}{n!} x^{n} & \text{take the derivative of both sides}\\
> \end{align*}

We apply this to where you got stuck.
$$E[X]= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{n+1}{n!} \lambda^n=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} e^{\lambda}(\lambda+1)=\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda}.$$

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, but I am stuck. I am unsure of how to simplify it any further from ((n+1)*lambda^(n-1)e^(-lambda))/(n!)

Comment: @jamie See my edit above